# is there any best approach in java multi thread environment to avoid a class execution in second time?

Tags: java, multithreading, jbpm

I have a class which has to be executed from JBPM process (multi-thread environment). During this first execution, if any condition is violated, I am adding a variable in a Map which means this transaction should be stopped temporarily.

But once the user has resolved this problem from UI, the same class will be executed again by the same JBPM process. Here, whatever, I have updated in the map in the first execution level is not available for this second execution. But, this time, I have to process this transaction even though conditional failures available.

I hope the sample code is not required for this to demonstrate.

How can I achieve this by skipping the execution the second time? Is there any design pattern which will support this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks you.

Comment: You have mentioned that it is same process, then any specific reason as to why this variable will not be available in the further execution. Ideally the variable should be persisted and be available in next action of same process execution.

Comment: This variable persistence is my first approach before writing to this. But, due to some project resstrictions, I can't be able to do this..

Comment: If you cannot use the default persistence tables of workflow engine, try persisting in some other tables or database with link to your workflow stage and then get the value when you require it.